# GSAP module issue with TweenMax in Quasar Framework

Tags: webpack, vue.js, gsap, quasar-framework

When I install gsap in a Quasar Framework project via

```
npm install gsap
```

and import in index.vue via:

```
<script>
import {TweenMax} from "gsap";
```

I can reference TweenLite in a method:

```
methods: {
    draw() {
         TweenLite.to("#c1", 1, {opacity:0.5, rotation:45});
```

But when I try to reference TweenMax, I get an error

```
TweenMax.to("#c1", 1, {opacity:0.5, rotation:45});
Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": 
     "TypeError: Cannot read property 'to' of undefined"
```

Any idea why TweenMax is not resolved? It looks like all the modules are available under node_modules/gsap…

thanks

Comment: test it, `import TweenMax from 'gsap';`

Comment: doh... that worked, now I'm puzzed...